# Why aren't peas mentioned in the Tanach/Talmud?

Tags: food, tanach, science, agriculture, archaeology

Or if my premise is wrong, please correct me?

*[Guns, Germs, & Steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guns,_Germs,_and_Steel)* talks about early domesticated crops of the [Fertile Crescent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fertile_Crescent). No surprise that he quickly mentions wheat, barley, olives, dates, grapes, figs, and pomegranates. He then talks about peas, lentils, and bitter vetch.

Lentils we've all seen early in the Torah, Jacob's stew. (There are plenty of Talmudic stories about lentils as well.) Vetch (*karshinin*) comes up in one halachic conversation or another several times in the Talmud. But where are the peas?

Comment: Have you searched "peas" on Sefaria?

Comment: Yevamot 63a: https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.63a.12?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Kilayim 1:1 https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Kilayim.1.1?ven=Eighteen_Treatises_from_the_Mishna&lang=bi

Comment: Are we restricting this to *pisum sativum*? Or other legumes with the word 'pea' in their common names?

Comment: Difficult to know if the peas above are the ones you are referring to

Comment: https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/legumes

Comment: @not in Tanach but it does appear in Mishnah. However, even in the Mishnah it is unlikely to refer (as it does today in Modern Hebrew) to the garden pea (*pisum sativum*).

Comment: @JoelK It's clear that the identification is a different story. I thought אפונה was a neologism, so it's not worth searching it. But the answer is there in the encyclopedia entry that you've posted.

Comment: What is פול המצרי and שיעור כגריס? Are they not beans of one sort or another?

Comment: @DoubleAA according to Prof Yehuda Feliks, a specialist of botany in Tanakh and Mishna, פול המצרי (Egyptian bean) is a [cowpea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowpea) - of course Mishna Shviit is full of these

Comment: @DoubleAA and a *gris* appears to be a split bean. It is found in Niddah 8:2 and Negaim 6:1 (and many other places)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to genus Vigna or Pisum?

Vigna or Black eyed peas are mentioned several times in the Gemara.

Comment: Hi Ruvain and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I recommend you edit in sources to your answer as evidence for what you state.

Comment: Black eyed peas are used as the siman Rubiya (cf. "increase") by Edot Mizrach